# php one_liner if compared to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I've recently programmed a lot in javascript and I was trying to use some shorthands in PHP.

Consider this statement:

```
$value = 1;

return $value == 1 ?
    'a' : $value == 2 ? 'b' : 'c';
```

Could anyone explain me why this returns `'a'` in jQuery and `'b'` in php?

Comment: It evaluates the first condition and returns 'a'. A JavaScript ternary should do the same thing.

Comment: Nested ternaries are a very bad idea

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In PHP, the ternary operator is [left-associative](http://phpsadness.com/sad/30) (or from [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), a little less clear).

> this is because ternary expressions are evaluated from left to right

In Javascript, the ternary operator is [right-associative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

> note: the conditional operator is right associative

So, in PHP your code executes like this:

```
($value == 1 ?
    'a' : $value == 2) ? 'b' : 'c';
```

And in Javascript, it executes like this:

```
value == 1 ?
    'a' : (value == 2 ? 'b' : 'c');
```

So, to get the same results, you need to tell either one to act like the other:

```
echo $value == 1 ?
    'a' : ($value == 2 ? 'b' : 'c');
```

This is (one of the?) the reason why nested ternary operators are a bad idea. [They're not readable](http://twistedoakstudios.com/blog/Post5273_how-to-read-nested-ternary-operators) and prone to these kind of mistakes!

Comment: however,Nested ternaries is   really a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the "else" part of the condition in parantheses

```
$value = 1;

echo $value == 1 ? 'a' : ($value == 2 ? 'b' : 'c');
```

This would return 'a' in php

Answer (score 1):

Use parenthesis do define the correct order of evaluation :

```
$value == 1 ? 'a' : ($value == 2 ? 'b' : 'c')
```